# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in darts file

Tags: java, random

The purpose of this program is to find an estimate of pi. At first it ran but the values were too large `(20,30,,40,etc)` and now it does not even compile. I get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.
 How would you go on fixing the code? Thanks.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
     public class Darts
    {   
     public static double[] getPi(double[] pi, int trials, int times, int counter)
     {
       for (int loop = 0; loop < trials; loop++)
     {
       for (int r = 0; r < times; r++)
       {
       double x = Math.random(); 
       double y = Math.random(); 


       if (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) <= 1)
       {
         counter++;
       }


       }
       pi[trials] = 4 * (double) counter / times;

     }
       return pi;
     }
    public static void printResults(double[] pi, int trials, double average)
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < trials; x++)
      {
        System.out.println("Trial [ " + x + "]: pi = " + pi[x]);                                             
      }
        System.out.println("Estimate of pi = " + average ); 
      }

      public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
      { 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int counter = 0;
      double y = 0;
      double x = 0;  
      double radius = 1.0;
      Random randNumList = new Random(); 


     System.out.println("How many times darts should be thrown in a trial?");
     int times = in.nextInt();

     System.out.print("How many trials will there be?");
     int trials = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println(" " + trials + " trials");

     double pi[] = new double[trials];
     pi = getPi(pi, times, trials, counter);

     double sumPi = 0.0;
     for (int l = 0; l < trials; l++)
     {
       sumPi += pi[l];
     }
     double average = sumPi/counter;
     printResults(pi, trials, average);


    }
  }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see exactly where the index of the array goes out of bounds. Also try to fix the code formatting, it's very hard to read

Comment: It doesn't compile?  Or it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?  You can't have both.  If it compiles OK, then I would recommend stepping through it with a debugger to see what's going wrong.  I'm sure you'll see your error immediately.

Comment: Sorry, it does compile

Comment: OK, I see two errors without actually looking too hard.  The line near the end that says `double average = sumPi / counter;` should say `double average = sumPi / trials;` instead.  Also, you're not resetting `counter` to zero at the beginning of the outer loop in the `getPi` method.  But I don't see how either of those is giving you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ah, now I see the two answers that have appeared so far.  They're both correct, and rolfl's answer describes the reason for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  So now, four mistakes in your code, possibly more.

Comment: Great.  Happy to help.  Good luck with your ongoing learning.

Comment: Note: [this post inspired a question on Code Review: Pi by Monte Carlo](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/74780/31503)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line here:

```
pi[trials] = 4 * (double) counter / times;
```

should be:

```
pi[loop] = 4 * (double) counter / times;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I am getting large values. how can I fix that?

Comment: Let's deal with one question at a time in each question here. With the running code, you should be able to debug it better.... but, as a hint, what is the value of 'counter', and what do you do with it?

Comment: I have no clue honestly

Comment: I reset the counter to 0

Comment: Got a second to chat about your code [in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19705/discuss-pi)?